# How can i write a complex model in dart for a installment app

Tags: flutter

I want to achieve the goal that you can see in the image below
I am new to flutter so kindly provide some explanation too

[image: this is what i want to achieve]

in this picture you can see that i am working on an installment app that shows duration and and installment paid in a month
here is what i want to implement

1. The Admin can add the installment paid with and save it to the database
2. if installment plan of 3 months is selected then 3 months should be added to the duration and if 6 months then 6 months and so on
3. The admin can add select whether the customer has paid the installment or not and the app updates accordingly
   i hope you have an idea
   here is the model i have created how can i modify it

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

class InstallmentsModel {
  final double amount;
  final String installmentPlan;
  final List installemtnPlanwords;
  // final double durationnum;
  final List planMonths;
  // final double monthlyPayment;
  // final String durationWords;
  final bool isPaid;
  final double total;
  // final String monthPaid;
  final String paymentDate;
  InstallmentsModel({
    required this.amount,

    // required this.durationWords,
    // required this.monthlyPayment,
    required this.isPaid,
    // required this.monthPaid,
    required this.planMonths,
    required this.installmentPlan,
    required this.paymentDate,
    required this.installemtnPlanwords,
  }) : total = amount * 3;
}

List<InstallmentsModel> installments = [
  InstallmentsModel(
      amount: 16500,
      installmentPlan: '3',
      installemtnPlanwords: ['Months', 'Years'],
      planMonths: ['October', 'November', 'December'],
      isPaid: true,
      paymentDate: '12 April')
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this model

```
class InstallmentsModel {
  final List<InstallmentPeriod> installmentPeriods;
  final String installmentPlan;

  InstallmentsModel({
    required this.installmentPeriods,
    required this.installmentPlan,
  });

  double get totalPaid {
    double total = 0;
    for (var installment in installmentPeriods) {
      if (installment.isPaid == true) {
        total += installment.amount;
      }
    }
    return total;
  }

  double get totalUnPaid {
    double total = 0;
    for (var installment in installmentPeriods) {
      if (installment.isPaid == false) {
        total += installment.amount;
      }
    }
    return total;
  }
}

class InstallmentPeriod {
  String? period; // like october, november, december
  bool? isPaid;
  String? paymentDate; // if isPaid is true then paymentDate will be there
  double? amountRequired; // the amount required to be paid
  double amount = 0; // the amount paid and 0 by default

  InstallmentPeriod(
      {this.period,
      this.isPaid,
      this.paymentDate,
      this.amountRequired,
      this.amount = 0});
}

List<InstallmentsModel> installments = [
  InstallmentsModel(
    installmentPlan: 'Monthly',
    installmentPeriods: [
      InstallmentPeriod(
        period: 'October',
        isPaid: true,
        paymentDate: '10/10/2021',
        amountRequired: 1000,
        amount: 1000,
      ),
      InstallmentPeriod(
        period: 'November',
        isPaid: true,
        paymentDate: '10/11/2021',
        amountRequired: 1000,
        amount: 1000,
      ),
      InstallmentPeriod(
        period: 'December',
        isPaid: false,
        amountRequired: 1000,
      ),
    ],
  ),
];
```